# How to install Mysql 5.1 on Fedora 16

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora, rpm, yum

I can't seem to install MySQL 5.1 on Fedora 16.  When I try to install an RPM downloaded from the MySQL website I get conflict errors with the existing 5.5 packages which I have already 'removed' via yum.

TIA SO

```
# yum localinstall MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm 


Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm: MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64
Marking MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-server.x86_64 0:5.1.60-1.glibc23 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=======================================================================================================
 Package           Arch        Version                Repository                                  Size
=======================================================================================================
Installing:
 MySQL-server      x86_64      5.1.60-1.glibc23       /MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64       42 M

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================
Install       1 Package

Total size: 42 M
Installed size: 42 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Check
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.1.60-1.glibc23.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.fc16.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Comment: Come TO easy points!  I already solved it.

Comment: I'm sure you have a good reason to prefer mysql 5.1 over 5.5.  I would rather adapt my existing apps than use an old version.

Comment: I think that installing an old version (5.1) of a software instead of a newer, more robust and more current version (MySQL 5.5) is almost always a mistake. You really should explain well why you want to install an old version like 5.1 (it has more security holes that 5.5)

Comment: Is you application (which motivates you -probably wrongly in my view- to install MySQL 5.1) not working with MySQL 5.5? Why? Won't it be simpler to correct or improve your application instead of severely downgrading your MySQL??

Comment: We can't have our way all the time.  Of course I would rather use the latest version.  Thanks for the down vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you still have an old mysql 5.5 package that conflicts with your attempted 5.1 install.

Doing a :

> yum remove mysql-libs

should remove it and allow you to properly install your MySQL 5.1 server package.